# Cannot link to libglew or libglfw

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, linker, glew

I'm following a (modified) version of [this OpenGL tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/#building-on-linux).

With this trivial source file:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>

int main() {
    glewInit();
}
```

And this makefile:

```
cflags=-ggdb -Wall -std=c++17

all: 01

01: 01.o makefile
    g++ $(cflags) $(shell pkg-config --libs glew glfw3 glm) -o $@ $<
01.o: 01.cpp makefile
    g++ $(cflags) $(shell pkg-config --cflags glew glfw3 glm) -o $@ $< -c

# The following have pkg-config entries:
# x11 xext glu glfw3 glew glm
```

It can compile but not link.

```
$ make
g++ -ggdb -Wall -std=c++17 -I/usr/include/libdrm -o 01.o 01.cpp -c
g++ -ggdb -Wall -std=c++17 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lglfw -o 01 01.o
/usr/bin/ld: 01.o: in function `main':
/home/greg/OpenGL_GEOM_2D/01/01.cpp:6: undefined reference to `glewInit'
```

Checking what `pkg-config` is doing in the background:

```
$ pkg-config --libs glew
-lGLEW -lGLU -lGL
```

The library it's using is here:

```
$ dpkg-query -L libglew-dev
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
```

That file definitely does have the symbols that are failing to link:

```
$ readelf -Ws /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so | grep glewInit
1146: 000000000005f2f0 38819 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 glewInit
```

So what's going on? Why is the linker failing to find that symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the old GNU linker the order of inputs specified on the command line does matter. It makes a difference if the libraries are specified before or after the input object files.

Try this for your Makefile

```
01: 01.o makefile
    g++ -o $@ $< $(shell pkg-config --libs glew glfw3 glm)
```

BTW, you should learn about implicit rules, your whole Makefile can be replaced with:

```
.PHONY: 01
all: 01

01: LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs glew glfw3 glm)
01: 01.o

01.o: CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags glew glfw3 glm)
01.o: 01.cpp Makefile
```

Thanks to the implcit rules you don't have to write the actual commands at all, just set the desired variables.

Comment: It did turn out to be library order - nasty. I'm going with the -( -) grouping options so that this doesn't matter (this should be the default behaviour anyway...)

Comment: As for the implicit rules, that's not going to happen, because this is a learning project for a friend, so everything needs to be explicit.

Comment: Also it appears that you've reversed your pkg-config invocations.